# How can I send header with X-Frame-Options DENY with the PHP Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, http-headers

I'm trying to **DENY iframe** calling my website with the **PHP framework Yii**.

I added this line in the top of '*index.php*' or in the '*protected/views/layouts/main.php*'

```
<?php header("X-Frame-Options: DENY") ?>
```

But I still have the possibility to create an iframe with the 'src' property of my website!

I'm trying too : add in the '*.htaccess*' :

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
```

Comment: Did you verify wether the header is sent, e.g. with firebug or chrome developer tools?

Comment: Yes, and no header property X-Frame-Options sent! Now, I resolved by added meta data in the head of the page: <head><meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="DENY"></head>

Comment: did somebody manage to solve this issue? It's been two years since OP asked this and there is still no solution for php that would work.
PS: Since meta tags in the head is ignored , I don't consider official answer as sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by added meta data in the head of the page:

```
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="DENY">
</head>
```

Comment: Using meta http-equiv tags is not allowed according to the RFC, and will not  work according to OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Common_Defense_Mistakes

Comment: It will not work. Proof [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Examples). Browser error:
X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside <meta>.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by configuring the `response` component of the application and adding custom headers in the `beforeSend` event, e.g.:

```php
return [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'response' => [
            'on beforeSend' => function($event) {
                $event->sender->headers->add('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
            },
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

This will add the header(s) for all responses. This may not be appropriate, in which case, you can use `\Yii::$app->response->headers->add($name, $value);` before returning from an action or in the `afterAction()` method of the controller.

It is well documented that the meta http-equiv tag does not work for this situation. In my opinion, http-equiv should never be used if you can set the header properly server-side.

The reason that the PHP `header()` function does not work is because Yii's response component resets all headers before preparing the response to send.

Comment: are you sure it's working? tried it now with no success " 'response' => array(
            'on beforeSend' => function($event) {
                $event->sender->headers->add('X-Frame-Options', 'DENY');
                },
            ),"

Comment: Worked for me. Added this to the configuration for my frontend application along with Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on how to modify headers sent by YII framework (v2)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html#http-headers

HTTP Headers

You can send HTTP headers by manipulating the header collection in the response component. For example,

```
$headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;

// add a Pragma header. Existing Pragma headers will NOT be overwritten.

    $headers->add('Pragma', 'no-cache');

// set a Pragma header. Any existing Pragma headers will be discarded.

    $headers->set('Pragma', 'no-cache');

// remove Pragma header(s) and return the removed Pragma header values in an array

    $values = $headers->remove('Pragma');
```

Answer (score 0):

In YII style we can do it using `registerMetaTag`. Add the following code in view or layout or controller.

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag('DENY', null, null, array('http-equiv'=>'X-FRAME-OPTIONS')); ?>
```

It will add `<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="DENY">` in the head tag.

For more details about `registerMetaTag` see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerMetaTag-detail).

Comment: As mentioned in comments on other answers, the meta tag method does not work for this use case and http-equiv is sub-optimal anyway - set the header server side if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the controller

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    /**
     * Clickjacking protection for Yii1
     */
    if (version_compare(\Yii::getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<')) {
        header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

protected function afterAction($action)
{
    /**
     * Clickjacking protection for Yii2
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342321/5546916
     */
    if (version_compare(\Yii::getVersion(), '2.0.0', '>=')) {
        \Yii::app()->response->headers->add('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
    }
    return parent::afterAction($action);
}
```